# Sanify Excel File uploaded to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am writing a procedure for an ASP.NET page in which user upload an Excel file containing a list of codes.

Because the user that do the upload is untrusted, i am afraid that a specifically a dangerouse Excel file may be uploaded. I am not concerned to much about macros (because when i parse the file I ignore them) but that a specifically crafted Excel file may cause (in the comopnent i use for parsing) some unpredictable bheaviour (for example remote code execution).

In summary i am used to sanitize all user input in my ASP.NET project, but don't know how to sanitize the uplaoded Excel file, so i have a security concern that don't know how to hanlde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple answer is to not use any Excel objects and automation. Remember, if you re-name a excel file to a .zip file extension?

then you can then open the zip file, and look inside. Things like the data, code/macros and other things will be seen by you the developer.

So, I would allow up-load of the file, but THEN process out the data via XML and place that into a new excel sheet. At that point, you are "leaving" behind the original file, and will have ONLY pulled the data, and ONLY have pulled the data by looking at the xml file part of the excel sheet - not EVER even using Excel to open, copy, transfer the data.

The end result is a new Excel sheet, and one that never been "automated" by Excel, but a resulting Excel sheet created by a raw xml copy. That raw XML "copy" thus will leave behind any and all other aspects of the original Excel sheet up-loaded, such as code or anything else like add-ins or what not.

This does mean you can't support the previous Office (up to 2003) "binary" xls files, but will only accept xlsx files. Furthermore you ONLY copy the xml out of that file, not copy nor use the Excel file EVER at any point in time, and will NEVER have opened the Excel file with Excel application.

So, I suggest using openxml, since XML files don't have a code or malicious ability's.

In other words, YOUR software will create the final Excel file, and your software will have created that Excel file by copy of xml data only, and thus nothing else in the up-loaded file will be used, nor transferred into that new Excel sheet. and you not even have used Excel to create that resulting file.

The end result will be at least a security level of that of dealing with a XML file, or say having allowed users to up-load a XML file.
So, such files are these days is the "glue" that runs most web sites and internet technology.

Despite the rise of json as a data format, a web page really is a "DOM", and that DOM really is xml format for the most part. So, the tools, the ideas, the concepts we use in this industry? It is very XML centric. And to be fair in this context while I used the term XML, it really is in .net land XXMAL, but it still really a "tag" based delimited structure we are dealing with.

So, a pull out of the xml data in that Excel file, and then discarding that original up-loaded file should provide a high level of security and leave behind in the original up-load anything malicious.

So, as long as you not ever launching that up-loaded file (maybe it is a .exe file faked out with a Excel file extension!!!!), then you shoul be fine security wise.

## Edit: Example useing closedXML.

So, this is "air code" or proof of concept code.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sFile = @"c:\test\tblHotelsA.xlsx";
        string sFileout = @"c:\test\tblHotelsAR.xlsx";

        XLWorkbook MyExcel = new XLWorkbook(sFile);
        XLWorkbook MyTargetExcel = new XLWorkbook();
        IXLWorksheet MyTargetSheet = MyTargetExcel.Worksheets.Add("mytarget");

        if (MyExcel.Worksheets.Count >= 0)
        {
            // get first work book, process 
            IXLWorksheet MyWorkBook = MyExcel.Worksheet(1);
            MyWorkBook.CopyTo(MyTargetExcel);
            MyTargetExcel.SaveAs(sFileout);
        }
    }
```

Now, of course above is hard coded file name. So, you no doubt take the orginal file name that user up-loads and you saved. You can then say add "-processed.xlxs" to the file name, and then copy the data to this new created sheet - one that YOUR code created, and one not created by the customer.

there are boatloads of examples. I in above probably should keep the workbook name the same, but you might adopt a standard for automated imports to a database, and thus "normalize" even the work book names to always be the same.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I don't know exactly how libraries like ExcelDataReader work internally, but the fact that they does not rely over Excel dependencies, let me think that probably those procuts proceede as you describe. At the moment i use such library (ExcelDataReader) to process trusted Excel. Do you think i can keep use, safely, such library to extrapolate data even from untrusted Excel?

Comment: Yes, and I made a mistake in the name - the library I suggest is called closedXML. I just posted a example code.